# How to rearrange post ID starting from the beginning

Tags: wordpress, optimization, indexing

I'm currently trying to reorganize my database and would like to optimize all the post ID in a table.

I have some post, each of them have an ID but given that some posts have been deleted there are holes:

```
post-one: ID => 1
// 2 is missing
post-two: ID => 3
// 4 -> 6 are missing
post-three: ID => 7
..
```

So I have only fifty posts but the last post ID is 280. After optimization I would like to have this result :

```
post-one: ID => 1
post-two: ID => 2
post-three: ID => 3
..
```

I search on Google and just here but nothing found but the [MySQL Optimize](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimize-table.html)  documentation, but it doesn't really helped me.

How can rearrange all the ID?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What would be "optimal", exactly? What problem are you actually trying to solve? You're unlikely to run out of integers... (I'd imagine it would be a lot of work, given that there may be post IDs scattered all through the database, including in serialised PHP data...)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I edited my post and added more explanations about my problem and what I want to do.

Comment: If you want risk your day, google "mysql auto increment reset"? Don't forget the post ids are foreign key other tables. May be create a new wordpress install and export & import posts from  old one. Don't call this process optimization. I don't know your use case! - Are you trying to beautify your post urls with serial numbers??

Comment: Why so sarcastic ? I posted to have answer and eventually advice on my problem. Maybe there is a benefit you don't know too.

@Gowri I'm looking for a plugin which maybe can do it ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer, do **not** do that, period. You are going to stuff up all relationships between posts and its relative terms, comments, custom fields, other related meta info and author info

Wordpress uses the post ID's to create relationships between post meta data (like thumbnails, images, video' etc), comments, terms and custom fields. Post ID's is also used to create parent-child relationships between posts of a hierarchical post type (like pages). All the abovementioned are stored in other tables within the db, and not in `wp_posts` (except parent-child relationships between posts). If you change the post ID in `wp_posts`, the post will loose all other data related to it. If the new post ID was previously used for another post, the new post will simply inherit all the data that was attached to the other post

Do not open this can of worms, if you change the post ID, there is no way of changing everything back, except from a backup

Comment: Ok, thanks! I knew there was relations between each table, I thought we could organize dynamically.

So I'm going to delete (and save it) my BDD and start with a new one.

Comment: Not going to help at all. Post revisions and all attachments are saved as posts. So post 1 will revision and autodraft saves as post ID 2 and 3, so post 2 will then be ID 4. You are going to work to a pointless point which goes in an infinite circle

Comment: If you delete the attachments and revisions, you will again have "ID holes"

Comment: Yeah I know, but the database I currently have was for tests, no we pass to production so I think it's better to start with a new database which include only that we decided is a good choice.

Comment: Well, I gave you advice, if you still want to do it your way, then go for it, but personally, I would not even do that effort. Post ID's will never ever be sequential, no matter what. Period. So you exercise still stay very useless

Comment: There is absolutely no benefit in what you want to achieve. And I'm not being sarcastic or anything, it is a **fact**

Comment: Thank you very much to helping me when so much others aren't positive.
Yeah, I understand. I pass the topic as resolved.